# Searching font and color item for displaying Debug values in editor

Tags: debugging, themes, visual-studio-2019

I want to edit the background and foreground color from this items, that show the current variable value:

[image: Debug value items]

I already searched at **Options > Fonts and Colors > Text Editor** all the available items but couldn't find it.
Can someone tell me which item is responsbile for that appearance?

I am using a [custom theme](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=J-Flepp.JFleppVsThemeDarkYellow) from the VS marketplace + ReSharper.

Comment: Could you please share a sample of your project with us to test it?

Comment: What do you mean with sample? I mean it has nothing do to with my code. It's probably because I'm using a custom theme from the VS marketplace + ReSharper.  
I think therefore both of them get in each other's way, but the possibilty to change the font color for this option must be somewhere in the settings. I will provide a link to the theme in the question.

Comment: @Stan1k, it is quite strange. The color of your function seems not to be a feature of default vs ide. Did you enable the two extensions and change its settings for that. And also, the variable seems not to be focused under the current cursor. Did you use any other option to make it highlight？ In my side, it cannot be highlighted.

Comment: I just tested it out by disabling my theme extension. Now the parameter values that you see on the picture above don't have a white but black background. Therefore I guess there must be an option in the `Fonts and Colors` menu to change the color for this item. But I still don't know which it is.

Comment: Ok, I will check that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature comes from ReSharper. So, please look for the `ReSharper Debugger Datatips` item in `Options | Fonts and Colors | Text Editor` and check the background color. Then restart Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this is your requirement:

**Current statement**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I just checked it out and unfortunately it does not meet my need. But it's close to that - it highlights the **current Debugging line** but not the variable and parameter values to the right. It looks like it must be hidden somewhere :D